# Which SMS gateway is best for getting world-wide service with all service providers

Tags: sms, mobile-application, sms-gateway

I am developing a mobile application, which needs a SMS verification scenario. So which one is the best solution. I have created one account with www.nexmo.com. But their service is not available for some service providers in some countries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We used to use Clickatel but they seemed to have a poor delivery rate, we now use Twilio and it works really well.

Comment: Is Twilio has service available in all countries and networks?

Comment: Checkout https://www.twilio.com/international to see where they support. They seem to have lots, though we've only used them in Europe and North America.